# How to select records that meets specific criteria

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the result for a particular ID if only all the "Prospect" have after it "Qualify" if not all the calculations will be dropped

Below is an example sample and output. How it can be done using SQL queries?

```
+----+----------+-----------+-------+
| id |  stage   | nextstage | value1 |
+----+----------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | prospect | qualify   |   200 |
|  1 | solution | develop   |   500 |
|  1 | prospect | null      |   400 |
|  2 | prospect | qualify   |   100 |
|  2 | develop  | solution  |   300 |
|  2 | prospect | qualify   |   100 |
+----+----------+-----------+-------+
```

**Output:**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | time in P2Q |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | NULL        |
|  2 | 200         |
+----+-------------+
```

I have tried the following but didn't know how to drop the entire calculation if there is one prospect record that doesn't have qualify after it

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN stage = 'Prospect' and nextstage='Qualify'  THEN value1 END) AS timeP2Q
from table1
group by ID
```

Comment: Can you please expand your question with required output model?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I did the following:

Created table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  stage VARCHAR (10),
  nextstage VARCHAR (10),
  value1 INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table1 
VALUES
(1, 'prospect', 'qualify' , 200),
(1, 'solution', 'develop' , 200),
(1, 'prospect',  NULL     , 200),
(2, 'prospect', 'qualify' , 100),
(2, 'develop' , 'solution', 200),
(2, 'prospect', 'qualify' , 100);
```

Then ran the following query:

```
SELECT id, timeP2Q FROM
(
  SELECT
    id,
    SUM
    (
      CASE 
        WHEN stage = 'prospect' and nextstage = 'qualify'  THEN value1 END
    ) AS timeP2Q
  FROM table1
  WHERE id NOT IN
  (
    SELECT id 
    FROM table1
    WHERE stage = 'prospect' AND nextstage IS NULL
  )
  GROUP BY id
) AS stuff  -- subqueries require an alias, not used.
ORDER BY id;
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
 id | timep2q 
----+---------
  2 |     200
(1 row)
```

The main query simply does the sum by id, and then the `WHERE id NOT IN` removes the unwanted ones. I think that there should be a date or a timestamp in there somewhere to be able to better extract information from this data! I see this as a process with stages?

Comment: Yes its a process with stages, there is time stamp but to simplify the example i put numbers. The query works great when there is one condition involved, but when it comes to more than one stage, and each stage has its own condition, it become difficult to contain all conditions in one `where` condition. for example, `timeD2S` gets omitted in `id 1` (it shoudnt be omitted) but the condition in the `where` effected the `id` to be removed as  the link [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ba44/2]

Comment: can u guide in this matter

Comment: OK - it's a bit clearer now - SQLFiddle (and ither such tools) certainly are a help when asking questions! I'll look at the SQL when I get to a machine. I still think that your data model requires some work. AIUI, these are projects which you undertake for customers? Is id a project id or a customer id? There should be timestamps associated with each of these records IMHO.

Comment: You'll have to repost  your SQLFiddle! Try [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) or for MSSQL Server, try [dbfiddle.uk](https://www.dbfiddle.uk) which can use it. Unfortunately, SQLFiddle has been (ahem...) troublesome for a while.